# How do I get the datatype of the value given the key of NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary and what to get the datatype for value given the key

is it possible?

Comment: Does a `NSDictionary` have a *first element*? I don't think enumeration has a guaranteed order.

Comment: A dictionary doesn't have a `first element` as you say. In an array, the elements are ordered but a dictionary just has key:value pairs that are not guaranteed to be in any order. Give an example of how you are trying to use this.

Comment: I fixed the quesiton, I mean the data type from value given the key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the variants you accept by

```
id objectValue = [dictionary valueForKey:@"SomeKey"];
if ([objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    //Object is a NSString
} else if ([objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
   //Object is a NSArray
} else if ([objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   //Object is a NSDictionary
} else if ([objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
   //Object is a NSNumber
}
```

And so on.. In this pattern just handle all the types your app supports. Ignore values your app doesn't support by this pattern or just fail gracefully in another way when you don't support the datatype of the value

To just figure out what class it is (to debug the application for example) you can do:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([objectValue class]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `NSStringFromClass` to get the type, or failing that you could use `isKindOfClass:`

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                           @"string": @"Something",
                           @"number": @(1),
                           @"null": [NSNull null],
                           @"custom": [[CustomType alloc] init]
                           };


[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
  NSLog(@"type = %@", NSStringFromClass([obj class]));
}];
```

output:

```
type = CustomType
type = NSNull
type = __NSCFNumber
type = __NSCFConstantString
```

Comment: Always kindOfClass because class clusters will tell you something you may not be able to use.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a lot of if-else statements, but it depends on his use for the output to the solution needed - which wasn't clear in the question.